# Ubuntu Server 16.04 routing issues

Tags: networking, server, router

I'm setting up my server to do all my routing. The LAN side seems to be working fine (dhcp is assigning IP and connecting) however there is no internet connection to any of the clients. But I can ping www.google.com from the server and I get a response. It seems like the server is connected to the internet but doesn't share the connection. I'm using `isc-dhcp-server`. Can someone help me?

Here is what I get when I run `ifconfig`

```
$ ifconfig
enp2s0    Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 68:05:ca:2d:94:4b
          inet addr:192.168.0.1  Bcast:192.168.0.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
          inet6 addr: fe80::6a05:caff:fe2d:944b/64 Scope:Link
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:2340 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:336 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000
          RX bytes:383418 (383.4 KB)  TX bytes:67244 (67.2 KB)
          Interrupt:17 Memory:fe9e0000-fea00000

enp3s0    Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 90:e6:ba:bd:6f:c9
          inet addr:71.234.240.97  Bcast:255.255.255.255  Mask:255.255.248.0
          inet6 addr: fe80::92e6:baff:febd:6fc9/64 Scope:Link
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:1305 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:2496 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000
          RX bytes:1235249 (1.2 MB)  TX bytes:251739 (251.7 KB)

lo        Link encap:Local Loopback
          inet addr:127.0.0.1  Mask:255.0.0.0
          inet6 addr: ::1/128 Scope:Host
          UP LOOPBACK RUNNING  MTU:65536  Metric:1
          RX packets:1625 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:1625 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1
          RX bytes:725919 (725.9 KB)  TX bytes:725919 (725.9 KB)
```

Answer (score 0):

> The LAN side seems to be working fine (dhcp is assigning ip and connecting) however there is no internet conection to any of the clients.

To give your client or guest on your **LAN** or **NAT** network access to internet, make sure that:

- Your Server can ping 8.8.8.8 or google.com
- Your client or guest can ping server gateway

Do to following:

`iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -p tcp -s 192.168.0.0/24 -j MASQUERADE`

Replace your network or just IP address of the HOST with the IP above, then from try to ping google.com or 8.8.8.8